# Averaging a one-to-one field will summing a one to many in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I put together this example to help

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51db24

The idea is I have 3 tables. One is the "root" table, in this case `person` which has a score attached to it. They then have some category I need to group by `person_cat.cat` and a one to many field called CS.

I would like to query for the average of the score, the sum of the one to many field `person_co.co` and group by the category.

```
SELECT
  person_cat.cat,
  person.id,
  SUM(person_co.co),
  AVG(person.cs)
FROM
  person
  LEFT JOIN person_co USING (id)
  LEFT JOIN person_cat USING (id)
GROUP BY cat;
```

The issue I'm currently having is the average gets thrown off due to the join for the one to many. I can accomplish this with multiple queries, which is ok if that is the answer. However it would be nice to get this as one query.

Comment: You must use multiple queries or subqueries; aggregate functions are processed after table rows have been joined. That said, I would expect the AVG result to be unaffected by this, as "Ax and Ay" has the same average as "Bx and By"; the SUM would definitely be affected though.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the answer. The sum is actually fine, the AVG is whats wrong in this example. the AVG function is coming back as 125 (the average of 100,100,100,200) instead of 150 (the average of 100,200)

Comment: Which one gets messed with will greatly depend on the data itself, and the grouping. _It does seem a little unusual to me to group on a field from a left joined table._

Comment: May I ask why? In this specific case we are aggregating data from various sources and its pretty common for a person to not to get a `cat`  assigned, however its still a relevant collection of persons

Comment: For one, since `person.id` is neither aggregated, nor grouped on; for the result with "no cats", you will end up with a effectively random id from on of the persons with no cats. Also, it is not clear whether the sum of `co` values for persons without cats is a useful result (or average of their `cs` values); but that is not necessarily wrong. I'm not saying the query is wrong, it is just a little different from "typical".

Comment: Also, it's not clear from the query whether multiple persons could be associated with the same "cat"; if such were the case, like the "no cat" case, those persons' `co` and `cs` values would be aggregated together and an effectively random id chosen from among the persons associated.